# indentation in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have some question about texstudio,

> - how to make an indentation in texstudio for several lines in the editor.  for example: make several lines add a Tab in front of it or
>     minus a Tab in front of several lines. Like what we can do in vim command `:> x,y`

Comment: more than one question in one post not good for site

Comment: Ok I will depart it into two question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all the lines and go to menu `idefix->indent` or `idefix->unindent`

[image]